# Next.js getting validation failed sending form data to contact form 7 API

Tags: javascript, api, post, next.js, contact-form-7

I am trying to send data to the Contact Form 7 API but get an error when sending the form:

```
{into: "#", status: "validation_failed", message: "One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again.", posted_data_hash: "", invalid_fields:
```

The input fields on the form have all the correct name values e.g. `name="your-name"`

I am sending form data like so:

```
  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = {};

    Array.from(e.currentTarget.elements).forEach((field) => {
      if (!field.name) return;
      formData[field.name] = field.value;
    });

    await fetch(
      "https://domain.tld/cms/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1234/feedback",
      {
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        headers: {
          "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
        method: "POST",
      }
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  }
```

I've tried it in Postman and it works and get status message send. I have no idea what I am doing wrong here.

Here's the form:

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Form.Group controlId="your-name">
      <Form.Control
        required
        type="text"
        placeholder="Your name"
        name="your-name"
      />
      <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
        Please enter your name
      </Form.Control.Feedback>
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group controlId="your-email">
      <Form.Control
        required
        type="email"
        placeholder="Your email address"
        name="your-email"
      />
      <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
        Please enter your email
      </Form.Control.Feedback>
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group controlId="your-message">
      <Form.Control
        as="textarea"
        cols={30}
        rows={6}
        placeholder="Write your message..."
        name="your-message"
      />
    </Form.Group>
    <Button
      type="submit"
      variant="primary"
      size="lg"
    >
      Send Message
      <span></span>
    </Button>
  </Form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using any `Content-Type` that starts with `multipart/*` you have to set the boundary, and there’s no boundary in your code.

To overcome that, just use `FormData` class like `const formData = new FormData()` and append values like `formData.append(key, value)` that way you will have a FormData instance so Axios can figure out what kind of a data you send, and it can set the Content-Type automatically with boundary.

Here’s the code that should work, I haven’t tested it though:

```js
async function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData();

  Array.from(e.currentTarget.elements).forEach((field) => {
    if (!field.name) return;
    formData.append(field.name, field.value);
  });

  await fetch(
    "https://domain.tld/cms/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1234/feedback",
    {
      body: formData,
      method: "POST",
    }
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It worked right away. I had no idea by setting boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked fine I am getting some issues when I successfully submit the form fields data still remains in the input field. also any idea about the file upload  I tried but it's storing the wrong path.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZGAy.png)

the code -

```js
export default function PageWithJSbasedForm() {
  // Handles the submit event on form submit.
  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();

    Array.from(event.currentTarget.elements).forEach((field) => {
      if (!field.name) return;
      formData.append(field.name, field.value);
    });

    await fetch(
      "http:/www.example.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/593/feedback ",
      {
        body: formData,
        method: "POST",
      }
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  }
  return (
    // We pass the event to the handleSubmit() function on submit.
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="yourName">Your Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="yourName" name="yourName" required />

      <label htmlFor="yourAge">Your Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="yourAge" name="yourAge" required />

      <label htmlFor="yourFile">Your Name</label>
      <input type="file" id="yourFile" name="yourFile" required />

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```